# VBA Paste array of cells between Workbooks at last Populated row (Paste not working?)

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, copy-paste, paste

I am trying to copy an array of data from a csv file to the next available row in a separate workbook in my "PowerBI_table" sheet (starting in column V). When I F8 through the code, no error codes appear, and the information is copied from the csv file -- however it does not paste the data in the workbook. Upon ending the macro, it has the array of cells in the workbook highlighted by they are empty.

How would you correct this?
Code below, image attached.

```
Sub copyWB2()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow_PowerBI_Table As Long
Dim lastRow_csv_file As Long


Set ws1 = Workbooks("stats.csv").Sheets("stats")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Dig_File.xlsm").Sheets("PowerBI_Table")

lastRow_PowerBI_Table = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row
lastRow_csv_file = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Activate
If IsEmpty([A2]) = False Then
ws1.Range("A1:G" & lastRow_csv_file).Copy ''' pick up here
ws2.Range("V" & lastRow_PowerBI_Table).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("stats.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
Else: MsgBox ("Error...This Workbook is Empty")
Workbooks("stats.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
End If
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: To clarify, the sheets themselves are properly named. So that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update: It seems like the issue was that data was already present in the row I was trying to start pasting at. A quick fix is by making the following updates:

```
'Not really the last row, but the first empty row now. 
    lastRow_PowerBI_Table = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws1.Range("A1:G" & lastRow_csv_file).Copy ws2.Range("V" & lastRow_PowerBI_Table)
```